# "Method definition not in @implementation context"?

Tags: objective-c

I put this in X-code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DrinkArray" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 self.drinks = tmpArray;
 [tmpArray release];
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

And it says this on the first line:

```
"Method Definition not an @implementation context"
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put "@implementation " at the beginning of your methods, and "@end" at the end of them?  Objective-C is like a preprocessor that turns code into C and so it needs help knowing when to do special processing on your Objective-C methods.

You seem to be trying to create a new ViewController, but you are doing it like a C programmer, instead of an Objective-C programmer.  You need to define a subclass of the ViewController class, which means you need an "@interface" section and an "@implementation" section.

You best plan of attack might be to tell X-Code to add a new file, and in the template-chooser dialog, tell it to make a subclass of UIViewController.  That will structure the code correctly.  You can also find many ViewController tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks, I just misplaced an import and put it right before.  I moved it up a few lines and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You put that method in the wrong place in your source file.  Look for a line that says `@implementation` and another that says `@end`.  Put your method in between there.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

one time.  I used

```
#import <stdlib.h>
```

and it seemed to work better.

I know you may not have done this in your particular situation, but I thought this might help others who view this question in the future.